# Search MS ACCESS database using Multiple Fields on the Web page - c#

Tags: c#

I have a search page having multiple text box and list box. I want to search based on one field or combination of fields.

I am connecting to MS ACCESS Database and displaying on the gridview.

Below is my Code.

I am adding each condition in a if else statement but i feel adding all condition in if else is not possible.

So is there any better way to do this??

```
Private DataTable getDataTable()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\\Project.accdb");
        string query;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Open the connection to db
        con.Open();

        var Merchant_ID = txt_MrchntID.Text;
        var Chain_ID = txt_ChnID.Text;
        var Reason_Code = txt_Reason.Text;
        var Date_From = Text_Date_From.Text;
        var Date_To = Text_Date_To;
        var Amt_From = txt_Amount_From.Text;
        var Amt_To = txt_Amount_To.Text;
        var Status = SELECT_Status.Text;
        var Tran_Type = Select_Trans_Type.Text;
        //Search by only Merchant ID.
        if (Merchant_ID.Length > 0 && Chain_ID == "" && Reason_Code =="" && Date_From== "" && Amt_From =="" && Status == "SELECT" && Tran_Type == "SELECT")
        {
            //Generating the query to fetch data

            query = @"select * from table where I_MRCHNT = '" + txt_MrchntID.Text + "' ";

            //cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);


            adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, con); 
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();


        }
        // Search by Merchant ID and Chain ID together.
        else if (Merchant_ID.Length > 0 && Chain_ID.Length > 0 && Reason_Code == "" && Date_From == "" && Amt_From == "" && Status == "SELECT" && Tran_Type == "SELECT")
        {

            //Generating the query to fetch data
            query = @"select * from table where I_MRCHNT = '" + txt_MrchntID.Text + "' and I_CHN = '" + txt_ChnID.Text + "' ";

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
            adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();


        }

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: Access db really is not designed for multi user access like this, you might want to consider switching to proper sql server (There are plenty of free ones out there) will likely save you trouble in the long run. Also you need to never ever put text directly in to strings like that, you need to be using parameters and passing them in that way. Also switching to something like EntityFramework to handle your database queries for you will make what you are trying to do a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your reply.
For my project my company is using MS ACCESS as DB they have plan to change the DB in future but as per now have to integrate with MS Access.
I am going to parametrize the query.
I tried for Entity framework but i see MS ACCESS does not allow this.

So is there any other way to do with MS ACCESS in easy way??
what if i added all criteria in if condition(it will be more than 50 Combination)
Then will it affect the performance??

Thanks

Comment: Doing a little googling I was able to find a [paid 3rd party provider](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/) that will let you use access with Entity framework

Comment: Thanks for the info..
I will work on this. Appreciate your help.